# handle special characters in hive using regex

Tags: regex, hive, special-characters, hiveql

I have data which comes up like this.

```
+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------+----------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+----------+
|     label    |     ent      |   custom1   |  account   | custom2  |     icp      |   created_by    |   approved_by   |    posted_by    |      date_posted      |        description        | group_1  |
+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------+----------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+----------+
| FB_FR_SE_1�  | 0418 - NORW  | D_ADJ_USD�  | 06D24CLS�  | ACC�     | [ICP None]�  | lbryan46@LDAP�  | lbryan46@LDAP�  | pprzyboc@LDAP�  | 7/5/2019 3:29:00 PM�  | Credit Loss Translation�  | FCEB�    |
```

i want to remove the tailing special character `�`

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hive is what am using here.

Comment: If you know precisely what is the caracter you want to escape, you don't need regex. You can use just a ```replace``` function/method in the language you use.

Answer (score 1):

using `regexp_replace`:

```
select regexp_replace('FB_FR_SE_1�','�','');
```

Result:

```
FB_FR_SE_1
```